# The last page in my questionnaire,replacing next button with a submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I'd like to make it so that the last page of my quiz has a submit button on the end. Right now what happens is the forward and back buttons appear if the quiz is empty, finished or out of questions.

When a group of four answers from the database do not show up (due to being empty strings) then how do I make it so that a Submit button appears and replaces the next button?

My SQL table consists of qid(int), answer(varchar), point(int)

**Code (PHP/HTML)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

$qid = 1; 
if(count($_POST) > 0){ 
$qid = intval($_POST['qid'])+1; 
}
?>  
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?=$qid?>">
            <?php
                $sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where answer != '' && qid =".intval($qid));
                while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
                ?>
                <input type='radio' name='answer1' value="<?php echo $row1['Point'];?>"><?php echo $row1['answer'];?><br>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
                <button type="button" onclick="history.back();">Tillbaka</button>
            <input type='submit' name='forward' value='Nästa'>

        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "When a group of four answers from the database do not show up (due to being empty strings)" Thats when you could display a submit button.

Comment: @Zapp Exactly! I just dont know how. Should I use javascript?

Comment: The connection to the database would be in another file. You would call the sql with ajax that file would detect if the "group of four answers from the database do not show up (due to being empty strings)", then it returns a submit button.